# Check if a MsgBox is already open (VBScript)

Tags: batch, vbscript

Message.bat:

```
@echo off
Start "" WScript //Nologo Message.vbs "Message 1" 0
Start "" WScript //Nologo Message.vbs "Message 2" 0
Start "" WScript //Nologo Message.vbs "Message 3" 0
```

Message.vbs:

```
Do While (msgbox is open?)
WScript.Sleep(500)
Loop
Message = Replace(WScript.Arguments(0),"\n",vbNewLine)
WScript.Quit MsgBox(Message,WScript.Arguments(1))
```

How do I to check if a msgbox is already open?
[wshShell.AppActivate("System Settings Change")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261157/vbscript-to-detect-an-open-messagebox-and-close-it?rq=1) not work.
My purpose is that the MsgBoxs must appear one at a time (and not all together as it happens) without suspending batch execution (the batch must close an instant after opening).
In other words, I want the same effect as:

Purpose.bat

```
@echo off
msg * Message 1
msg * Message 2
msg * Message 3
```

Comment: Msgbox is modal by default (waits for response). If you are trying to capture the result, use something like `result=msgbox(message,params)` and `wscript.Quit result`. As it stands now, your msgbox only get displayed at exit and is not inside the loop

Comment: This seems a bit unclear what exactly you are trying to accomplish here. I understand you want message 1, and then message 2, and then message 3 to pop up one after the other, right? So with the VBS `Do While` loop are you looking for conditional logic so if they press this on msgbox 1 then do this or this on msgbox 2 then do this, etc? Look over http://vbs.wikia.com/wiki/Do/Loop_Loop and see if that helps you any for some pointers when you get a chance. If you can clarify with detail what you are expecting as I asked you above—write it to me like I'm a kid and no nothing in detail.

Comment: This is a classic [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please explain the *entire* procedure you’re trying to achieve. Don’t skip any facts, even if they may appear trivial to you. // My take on this, based on incomplete knowledge, is that you should just use VBScript any nothing else.

Comment: I have explained with all the energy I had in body updating the "body".

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you would need to do is just check for whether an instance of your message box script was running. Would telling you how to do this be sufficient for an answer?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Sounds like you need to put that conditional login in the VBS logic as that link shows that I provided. Use the `IF THEN ELSE` logic so IF this then do that and so on. You may need to use `DO UNTIL` and put more than one loop to accomplish what you need to not pop up the next msgbox until someone pressed the option on the msgbox you are expecting, etc. Just play with some of that and see what you come up with and then [edit] your question with new detail, etc. but this should get you close. Let  us know how it goes once you start digging into it.

Comment: So don't get stuck in the thought that you need all these in the same one loop to make this happen if you want the VBS script to handle it as you explain. Just start playing with it and you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: I have Update the body.

Comment: Probably there is no way. I'll arrange it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `Start` with the switch `/Wait`

```
@echo off
Start "Msg1" /wait WScript //Nologo Message.vbs "Message 1" 0
Start "Msg2" /wait WScript //Nologo Message.vbs "Message 2" 0
Start "Msg3" /wait WScript //Nologo Message.vbs "Message 3" 0
```